# HP Officejet printing with only magenta ink, but copies fine with black ink

Tags: hp-officejet

My HP Officejet 5610xi All-in-One is printing oddly lately.  An all-black text document will print magenta text.  Printing color imagery also results in an all magenta result.  However, copying something either in color or black, it prints the black just fine.  Both ink cartridges are new as of a few days ago, when my wife first encountered this problem, assumed she was out of ink, and changed the cartridge.

I'm printing from OSX 10.6.8, and have not changed my printer setup since it worked correctly.   It is plugged in via USB.   Here are my printer settings:

[image]

Comment: Maybe a silly question but are the cartridges needing cleaning or changing. The copier may be using just the black cartridge and other docs printing using a mixture of the 3 primary colours, 2 of which are empty/ dried up. Some printers have a setting to always print text in black, i.e. use the black cartridge.

Comment: @brianA - good question, the answer is they are both new.

Comment: @brianA - oh yeah, and did cleaning, etc.  Also tried several printer diagnostics per HP's website (I should give a link however that was on another computer and I can't quickly find it again).